# Box-Shadow works on Chrome but not on Firefox or IE

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations, box-shadow

```
@-webkit-keyframes neon {
from {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF1177, 0 0 6px #FF1177, 0 0 9px #FF1177, 0 0 11px #FF1177, 0 0 14px #FF1177;
}
to {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF9900, 0 0 6px #FF9900, 0 0 9px #FF9900, 0 0 11px #FF9900, 0 0 14px #FF9900 inset;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes neon {
from {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF1177, 0 0 6px #FF1177, 0 0 9px #FF1177, 0 0 11px #FF1177, 0 0 14px #FF1177;
}
to {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF9900, 0 0 6px #FF9900, 0 0 9px #FF9900, 0 0 11px #FF9900, 0 0 14px #FF9900 inset;
}
}
@-o-keyframes neon {
from {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF1177, 0 0 6px #FF1177, 0 0 9px #FF1177, 0 0 11px #FF1177, 0 0 14px #FF1177;
}
to {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF9900, 0 0 6px #FF9900, 0 0 9px #FF9900, 0 0 11px #FF9900, 0 0 14px #FF9900 inset;
}
}
@keyframes neon {
from {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF1177, 0 0 6px #FF1177, 0 0 9px #FF1177, 0 0 11px #FF1177, 0 0 14px #FF1177;
}
to {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 5px #FF9900, 0 0 6px #FF9900, 0 0 9px #FF9900, 0 0 11px #FF9900, 0 0 14px #FF9900 inset;
}
}


.deallinkactive {
display: inline;
float: right;
width: 508px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 10px 10px 8px 8px;
border: 1.5px solid rgba(173, 38, 38, 0.541176);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
background: #ecf0f1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-animation: neon2 .2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: neon2 .2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
animation: neon2 .2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  }
```

The Box shadow animation is perfectly working on Chrome and Mobiles but not on IE and Firefox. I have tried -webkit-box-shadow , box-shadow , moz-box-shadow and all the things I found on internet. If I replace text-shadow in box-shadow, text-shadow works. Help!!

Comment: using -webkit- as a prefix means "this rule is only for the webkit rending engine" try removing it: instead of -webkit-box-shadow use box-shadow and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your class `.deallinkactive` is pointing to a wrong keyframe, it says `neon2`, change that to `neon`. then remove `-webkit-` from all `-webkit-box-shadow`. Finally, `@keyframes` not supported in an inline or scoped stylesheet in Firefox [bug 830056](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=830056).

But you have an alternate:

```
@keyframes neon {
    0% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(255,17,120,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(255,17,120,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(255,17,120,1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(255,153,0,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(255,153,0,1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(255,153,0,1);
    }
}

.deallinkactive {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 508px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 10px 10px 8px 8px;
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(173, 38, 38, 0.541176);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: #ecf0f1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    animation: neon .2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/1vma6m60/2/)

It works on modern browsers (chrome, firefox, safari, IE10+). Hope it helps.

Tip: try generating box-shadow using [cssmatic.com/box-shadow](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use moz for firefox

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

Try box shadow generator in css3
http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow